# HTML5 Web Worker Communication

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I'm trying to come up with a good way of calling functions in a web worker script and getting them to return values to the main script, I'm finding it kind of difficult to come up with something that is extensible since it's asynchronous and done via messaging, any help would be much appreciated. Here is my web worker script...

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var data = e.data;

    switch (data.cmd) {
        case 'call' :
            self[data.funcName](data.args);
            break;
        default:
            self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
        };

}, false);

function testWorkerFunction(args) {
    self.postMessage({'cmd': 'call', 'funcName': 'testClientFunction', 'args': args});
}
```

And here is my main script.

```
$(function() {
    var someOtherVal;
    worker = new Worker('js/workers/uc-main-worker.js');

    worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        console.log('Worker said: ', e.data);
        var data = e.data;

        switch (data.cmd) {
            case 'call' :
                self[data.funcName](data.args);
                break;
            default:
                console.log('Unknown command');
                break;
            };
    }, false);

    worker.onerror = function(e){
      throw new Error(e.message + " (" + e.filename + ":" + e.lineno + ")");
    };

    /* This is the bit I need some help with, how I can return a value back here */
    var someVal = messageWorker({'cmd': 'call', 'funcName': 'testWorkerFunction', 'args': 'hello'});
    //Not sure how to get a value back without invoking a function in the main script because I have to use messaging.

});

function messageWorker(message) {
    worker.postMessage(message);
}

function testClientFunction(args) {
    //Simply storing it as a global var.
    someOtherVal = args;
}
```

Hopefully from my code yo understand what I am after, at the moment I can get the value returned by the testWorkerFunction, but only by calling another function and or storing it as a global variable.

Answer (score 3):

Communicating with Workers can't be done synchronously, as they run in a different thread.
You have to use callbacks to achieve this communication.

If you want to make your code look more elegant than a callback "pyramid of doom", you can embrace the Promise pattern, and you can use [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [jQuery.deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

**EDIT:**
You can change your *messageWorker* method to look like this if you want to use "cleaner" callbacks.

```
function messageWorker(message, callback) {
    function listen(e){
        if (e.data.funcName === message.funcName){
            worker.removeEventListener("message". listen);
            callback(e.data.args);
        }
    }
    worker.addEventListener("message", listen)
    worker.postMessage(message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, so the way I have it coded right now, is that using a callback?

Comment: How can you pass in a callback function when you can only communicate using JSON?

Comment: In your example, the callback is the event handler function that's invoked on "message".

Comment: Ok I'm still unsure how I provide a callback function,  other than the one invoked on messages, I want to be able to call functions in my worker script and then have them call a callback function.

Comment: If worker.removeEventListener("message". listen); was commented out then my callbacks would be executed each time funcName were equal?

Comment: If your worker script can respond multiple times to the same call, you can drop the line with *removeEventListener*, and that'll do it for you. The way that the example is written right now, your code will be "waiting" for one response for each call to *messageWorker*.

Comment: The problem that will occur in doing that is, if you register interest in a worker function that executes multiple times because of data received via websockets. Then each callback will execute multiple times on one single execution of the script.

Comment: That's what I meant in my last comment. I believe that the way it is written in the answer above will match what you need. Try it and see if it works for you.

Comment: Say you had two callbacks registered with same function(A) in the worker script, then each callback function will be executed twice, I would want each callback function to executed once for each execution of function(A), the way it is written above you would achieve that, but only with one execution of function(A), if it happened to execute again, neither callback would execute. If you remove the line removeEventListener, then you would end up with multiple executions of each callback on a single execution of function(A)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [vkThread](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/) plugin. I think, it is what you're looking for. This plugin allows you to execute any function of a your code in a thread.

http://www.eslinstructor.net/vkthread/

Hope this helps,

--Vadim

Answer (score -1):

(After failing to find a solution anywhere else) I've come up with a fairly straightforward pattern for communicating with a web worker via callbacks that need access to calling code: https://gist.github.com/therightstuff/eb415798b0e30866fe85d66af68969cf

EDIT: wow, looking back at my original post I wonder if I wasn't having a stroke at the time. The link has been updated